# Drop all tables in sql server database using ant script

Tags: sql-server, ant, jdbc

Can anybody help me with this?

I prefer if I don't have to explicitly list the table names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw this before...

exec sp_MSforeachtable "DROP TABLE ? PRINT '? to be dropped' "

Source - http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/t-sql/archive/2008/05/20/4266.aspx

Comment: Yes - If you can install ant on windows and then use the sql command line SQLCMD.exe located here 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en .  Or if you're on Linux, you can probably find some kind of sql connectivity, yes?

Answer (score 0):

How about dropping the database?  `DROP DATABASE <database name>`

Of course, that's rough on stored procedures, triggers, etc.  But if the purpose is to eliminate all the tables in order to recreate them, it makes sense that you'd recreate all the other associated components as well, such as indexes.

Comment: Why drop the database? One would loose all the other objects as well.

Comment: It seems you anticipated my addendum.  Without the tables, there's very little value in the other objects.

Comment: That may work, but i'm not sure what will happen to  various settings like users roles etc, i don't think i can recreate them via ant.

Comment: It's been 8+ years since I've touched SQLserver, but Oracle and MySQL store the user roles separately from the database.  For permissions specific to a table, it would be unreasonable to expect those to survive a dropped table.